# Using User Defined Functions For A Specific Database in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How I can use a user defined function for a specific database (The use db statement is not working). Here are the images for the table and the query

I can't understand the errors which i am getting here. 
Please someone help.

[I have only a single table for now in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hAW.png)

[The Query][2]

```
Use Lab6

Create function fetch_orders (@P_Customer_ID int)
Returns int
AS 
Begin
    Return (Select Count (Order_ID) 
            From Orders 
            Where Customer_ID = @P_Customer_ID)
End
```

Comment: Please include the schema and the query as `code`, not as screenshots...

Comment: i had not made the schema yet but i have included the code of the query

Comment: I think what you want is to reference the function with "Select  dbo.fetch_Orders(1)"

Comment: its showing me error on create function line while referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GO after a USE statement:

```
USE Lab6
GO

CREATE FUNCTION ...
```